# Reformat code in EditPlus

Tags: reformatting, editplus

My favourite editor is EditPlus. But it lacks one thing that is how to reformat code. I searched many pages but I cannot find the way to do that. How can I do? (I don't want to change editor.)

Comment: Under the menu `Edit>Format` there are various options. `Ctrl+Shift+R` does provide a "reformat" feature, it may need to be customized per your file extension.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I tried to search and I did not know where or which file that I can  customized?

Comment: Under `Document > Permanent Settings` then look for `Settings and syntax`. Choose the file type in the upper portion of the dialog and set the suntax (.stx) file below. The syntax file contains the rules. You can find premade stx files for many common file types if you use Google and search for *EditPlus syntax files*.

Comment: @Octopus As of EditPlus 5.1, the settings are under `Tools > Preferences...`